# Html и php - админское меню

Tags: php

На сайте нужно реализовать несколько возможностей для админа.

Например:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$k = isset($_SESSION["admin"]);
?>

<html>
<head>
<style>
...
<?php if($k) { ?>
#div1 {position: absolute;}
<? } ?>
#div2 {position: fized;}
...
</style>
<script>

function A(){Реализация функции}

<?php if($k) { ?>
function A(){Другая реализация функции}
<? } ?>

</script>
</head>
<body>
...
<?php if($k) { ?>
<h1>Admin</h1>
<? } ?>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Хотел бы узнать, данную конструкцию можно применять?

Можно ли таким образом подключать те стили, которые нужны для админа.

Или менять реализацию функций?

Это корректно? Или по другому надо делать?

Кто может пожалуйста дать источник, где про это почитать?

Answer (score 1):

Технически так делать можно (за исключением переопределения уже определенной функции), но вы потом сами то сможете в таком коде разобраться?

Что касается стилей, я бы в данном случае для обычных пользователей описал их все в одном файле css (эти стили подключены всегда), а для админа выполнил переопределения в другом файле css и по if подключал этот админский css после клиентского. Так решится проблема со стилями.

Что касается реализаций функций, думаю, стоит именно в ней выполнять логику разделения через if, например, передавая через параметр:

```
function A(isAdmin = false) {
    if (isAdmin) {
        // Реализация функции
        return;
    }

    // Другая реализация функции
}
```

С заголовком, видимо, без вариантов.

Суть в том, чтобы максимально сократить количество if'ов в файле. Дополнительным плюсом был бы вынос логики из файла с представлением в отдельный файл, в котором формируются все изменяемые части представления, такие, как заголовок (т.е. сформировали там заголовок в переменную, и в представлении уже содержимое этой переменной выводите). А если повторяемых частей в представлении не так уж и много, может стоит вообще на отдельные файлы разнести код - для обычного пользователя подключать один файл, а для админа - другой.

Про смешивание php-кода с HTML можно почитать [в официальной документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

Comment: Добавлю, что вопрос со стилями решается куда проще, чем в примере автора:

    // Где-то в недрах кода формируем массив классов для body
    $bodyClasses = array();
    if ($k) {
        $bodyClasses[] = 'admin';
    }

Затем в шаблоне:

    <body class="<?php echo implode(' ', $bodyClasses); ?>">

И теперь в css в конце файла оверрайдим то, что нужно:

    .admin .some-class {
        position: absolute;
    }

Answer (score 0):

В чем проблема сделать так?

```
if($k){
   echo "function A(){}";//админская реализация
}else{
   echo "function A(){}";//обычная реализация
}
```